# Does Bison/Flex have a feature to declare a specific terminal as the error recovery reset point?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer, lexer

I am currently using the Bison feature `error` in my grammar rules in various places similar to the following:

```
nonterminal:
     someother_nonterminal SEMI
     | another_nonterminal SEMI
     | error SEMI {printf("Some helpful message"); yerrork;}
```

This works predictably for the most part. I just want to rely on the semicolon as the reset point for error reporting.  I understand no single general approach will work for all parsing errors (i.e. misleading cascading errors as a result of an initial error). I am looking for a more general and simple solution.  Is there a Bison declaration, perhaps something like %error_reset_terminal, that simply tells Bison to absorb any error up to the nearest semicolon (SEMI terminal label).

If such a feature exists, then I can avoid the shift-reduce headaches associated with error absorption in grammar rules.

I do not really need specific error handling messages.  My language implements features/keywords like using, namespace, and general struct like objects with braces.  As such, putting an error absorption rule in the starting nonterminal is not very helpful.  I am hoping Bison has a general declaration that I can use.

Comment: How is `error` not general enough? You only need it in one place in this case.

Comment: How would something like this work?  In order to recover from an error, bison needs to (a) find a state where it can continue and (b) find a token in the input where it can continue.  Just specifying the token as you suggest solves (b), but still leaves (a).  Putting an `error` production in a rule solves both.